# Multiple Definition - Why can't I define them in a header

Tags: c++, linker-errors, header-files, multiple-definition-error

I know... basics somehow but I don't get it. I read that I can put my function definition inside my header and include it then. I've never done that so far because I liked my definition in a .cpp file seperate to it's declaration in a header file.

Now I had just two functions and I don't want an extra file for those definitions.

Header.h

```
const QString reviewToString(const int); //Declaration - do I even need it now?
const QString statusToString(const int); //Declaration - do I even need it now?

const QString reviewToString(const int r) //Definition
{
    switch(r)
    {
    case 0:
        return "Excellent";
    case 1:
        return "Great";
    case 2:
        return "Okay";
    case 3:
        return "Poor";
    case 4:
        return "Terrible";
    default:
        return "Unknown";
    }
}

const QString statusToString(const int s) //Definition
{
    switch(s)
    {
    case 0:
        return "Watched";
    case 1:
        return "Bought";
    default:
        return "Not Watched";
    }
}
```

This is an extract of my headerfile. I got some other `enum`s and `struct`s but they're not that important for these functions because they just translate an integer to a QString which will be displayed somewhere else. I also have an include guard.

Now I get tons of errors like this one :

> multiple definition of `reviewToString(int)'

Why is that? Why can't I just declare and / or define them in this header?

Comment: Short answer: Use `inline`.

Comment: @MM. well that's smart! Thanks..

Comment: BTW: Don't mark the return type as `const`, please. It has no real benefit for your implementation of a function and the caller might feel offended as you take away some freedom of what to do with the object. Never mind some cases inducing come overhead...

Comment: @Daniel Frey, sometimes you want to take away those freedoms...

Comment: @jmstoker In some ***very rare*** cases, yes. But by default (and this seems to be the case here), just return non-`const`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `inline` to the definition. Without it, each translation unit will create its own copy and the linker will not know that those are supposed to be duplicates and that he is allowed to throw away all but one of those copies.

Better yet, don't add the definition to the header, just the declaration is enough. Move the implementation to its own translation unit (`.cpp`-file). You don't need the `inline` there and it has multiple benefits that become more and more important as your project grows.

Comment: Do you know why the include guards don't protect against this?

Comment: @jmstoker That's simple: They work per translation unit. They make sure each translation unit only contains a single copy which is nice but doesn't help the poor linker when you throw several translation units at it. The `inline` modifies the type of the exported symbol to help the linker deal with it, while the include guard is part of the preprocessor and long gone when the linker is invoked.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). (C++ Standard **§3.2**)

Basically, you can't have multiple definitions for a function in your entire program. You can however make the functions `inline` (otherwise, you'll have to put them in a `.cpp` file).